Docker, ngnix and ssl for local development
I am a developer and a beginner with Ngnix.
I try to enable ssl
so that I just can develop with https on my local.
I made a minimal example trying to keep it simple pushed my trial to my Git repo.
https://github.com/cptuulia/ngnix-ssl/tree/main
I have seen this example on many sites, but I cannot make it to work.
Can anybody help with this?
With this code I expect that when build and run my container by docker compose up and then open the link
https://tom.dev:8000 I should see
It works!

But I see

Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your information from tom.dev (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

With curl I see some more information:
curl https://tom.dev:8000 -verbose

* Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to tom.dev (127.0.0.1) port 8000
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
* CApath: none
* LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Closing connection
  curl: (35) LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Files

https://github.com/cptuulia/ngnix-ssl/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:

    nginx:
        container_name: nginx-ssl
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - 8000:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
            - .docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - .docker/nginx/certs/tom.dev.crt:/etc/nginx/ssl/tom.dev.crt
            - .docker/nginx/certs/tom.dev.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/tom.dev.key


https://github.com/cptuulia/ngnix-ssl/blob/main/.docker/nginx/nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl ;
        server_name tom.dev;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tom.dev.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tom.dev.key;

      location / {
        root /var/www/;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }
}

Certificates
I have tried with both of the methods, but I always get the same error. I am not sure which is the correct one and if my configuration is OK.
mkcert
 cd .docker/nginx/certscd
 mkcert "\*.tom.dev"

openssl
cd .docker/nginx/certs 

openssl req -x509 -nodes -new -sha256 -days 1024 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tom.dev.key -out tom.dev.pem -subj "/C=US/CN=Example-Root-CA" 

openssl x509 -outform pem -in tom.dev.pem -out tom.dev.crt


For this reason I switched to Caddy https://caddyserver.com , take a look, https everywhere!

In a development setup, you probably don't have a TLS certificate that's signed by a well-known certificate authority; in the last example you're just creating a new self-signed certificate.  Unless you can upload that certificate into your browser as trusted, you'll get a browser TLS trust error like that.
Because you know what you're connecting to and where the certificate came from you can safely click past it.
In your setup, you have both an unencrypted HTTP setup (container port 80, host port 8000) and an encrypted setup (both host and container ports 443).  You should use http://localhost:8000 (no s, should redirect) or https://localhost (default HTTP/TLS port 443), but not https://...:8000 (speaking HTTP/TLS to the plain-HTTP port).
You might be able to convince curl to accept the local CA certificate with a command-line option
curl https://tom.dev --cacert .docker/nginx/certs/tom.dev.crt

but a desktop browser will be trickier to set up.
